# How to generate random numbers between 0 and 1 in jax?

Tags: jax

How can I generate random numbers between 0 and 1 in jax?
Basically I am looking to replicate the following function from `numpy` in `jax`.

```
np.random.random(1000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent in jax would be

```python
from jax import random
key = random.PRNGKey(758493)  # Random seed is explicit in JAX
random.uniform(key, shape=(1000,))
```

For more information, see the documentation of the [`jax.random` module](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.random.html).

Also be aware that JAX's random number generator does not maintain any sort of global state, so you'll need to think about it a bit differently than you may be accustomed to in NumPy. For more background on this, see [JAX Sharp Bits: Random Numbers](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#random-numbers).